# Setting child directive's property based on parent component's property

Tags: angular

I have a child directive injecting a token used for a childproperty. And a parent component injecting the same token to implement parentproperty. Based on properties values different css styles are used.
Now I need to set the childproperty values to all of the children of the parent to be the same as the value of the parentproperty. This should be done on initialization. What is the best approach for achieving this?

Comment: Hi, do you want to use *ngFor directive for this?

Comment: No, I would rather do this in code as the parent component template contains ng-content element.